# QNetworkRequest failing with large header, ssl security, and authentication

Tags: qt, authentication, networking, https

I'm attempting to send some JSON with QNetworkRequest over an https connection with authentication.  Everything works fine if either 
1.  The size of the header is very small
2.  There is no authentication

My webserver is JBoss 4.2.3 (I can't upgrade because I'm using [dcm4che](http://www.dcm4che.org)) and my Qt version is 4.7.  Here is an example of code that works for me.

```
QVariantMap data;
QString query = "SELECT patient.pat_name FROM patient";
data["action"] = "get.worklist";
data["sql"] = query;
bool success;
// I'm using the QtJson project, which seems to work fine
QByteArray jsonData = QtJson::Json::serialize(data);
if (!success) {
    QString err = "There was a serialization error";
}
QUrl url(/*a valid URL*/);
url.setUserName(/*user*/);
url.setPassword(/*password*/);
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, jsonData.size());
request.setRawHeader("params-json", jsonData);

reply = manager.get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(httpFinished()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), SLOT(httpError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

void ServletConnection::sslErrors(QNetworkReply *reply,const QList<QSslError> &errors) {
    // There were ssl errors
    reply->ignoreSslErrors();
}

void ServletConnection::httpFinished() {
    QString error = reply->errorString();
    int e = reply->error();
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

If I change query to be a longer value such as "SELECT patient.pat_name, patient.pat_birthdate FROM patient" then I get an error.
Error string = "Error downloading URL - server replied: HTTP Version Not Supported"
Error number = 301 -- QNetworkReply::ProtocolUnknownError
However if I remove the authentication from the webserver (and leave the https), then everything works fine regardless of how long the query string is.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to do this.  I changed my get to a post and now I can post any amount of data successfully.

Comment: Would you share an example of how you used manager.post() ?  I'm curious how the username & password are added, whether through QByteArray.append("username=???") or if you rolled your own with QNetworkAccessManager's setRawHeader().